# Is the behavior of encryption platform specific- NotYetCommonsSSL java

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to use this code and wrote a test case- encrypting a plain text with secretkey1 and decrypting the output with secretkey2 would throw BadPaddingException.

But, I observed the behavior is different

- When I run it on my mac the test case succeeds.
- On linux the test case fails, which meant the decryption succeeded outputting a value.

Here is the differences I gathered. Appreciate any help pinpointing the issue.

### Mac

java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:115)
at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:233)
at org.apache.commons.ssl.Util.fill(Util.java:206)
at org.apache.commons.ssl.Util.streamToBytes(Util.java:156)
at org.apache.commons.ssl.OpenSSL.decrypt(OpenSSL.java:95)
at com.seatadvisor.crypto.SaboSecretTranslator.decrypt(SaboSecretTranslator.java:105)
at com.seatadvisor.crypto.SaboSecretTranslator.main(SaboSecretTranslator.java:163)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1970)
at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:112)
... 6 more
```

### Linux

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import org.apache.commons.ssl.OpenSSL;
import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

public class NotYetSslLibraryUsage
{
private final String secretKey;

public NotYetSslLibraryUsage(@Nonnull String secretKey)
{
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
}

public String getPlainText(@Nonnull String encryptedText)
{
    return new String(decrypt(encryptedText), Charsets.UTF_8);
}

private byte[] decrypt(@Nonnull String cipherText)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] plainText = OpenSSL.decrypt("aes128", secretKey.toCharArray(), cipherText.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));

        System.out.println(new String(plainText, Charsets.UTF_8));
        return requireNonNull(plainText, "plainText must be non-null");
    }
    catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        throw e;
    }
}

public void encrypt(@Nonnull String messageToEncrypt) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    byte[] aes128s = OpenSSL.encrypt("aes128", secretKey.toCharArray(), messageToEncrypt.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));

    System.out.println("===========================Encrypted=============================");
    System.out.println(new String(aes128s, Charsets.UTF_8));
    System.out.println("=================================================================");
}
```

}

Comment: *"encrypting a plain text with secretkey1 and decrypting the output with secretkey2 would throw BadPaddingException."* You've noticed that you're using AES? Your code also doesn't use different keys.

Answer (score 1):

If the code that produced the stack trace is like the code you included in your question, the problem lies with operations like these:

```
cipherText.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)
```

Cipher text isn't "text". It's sequence of unpredictable bytes that, in general, can't be decoded to characters.

If you need to represent cipher text as a printable character string, use base-64 encoding or something similar.